# DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query"{id:xxx}"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

hello I have a discord bot and I started to do a marriage and divorce command the case is that when I try to delete the user from the db I get the error

```
DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: new ObjectId("61ec3c66cb5991d616c6032d") }" on model "casados"
```

this is my model

```
const  mongoose = require("mongoose")
const casados = mongoose.Schema({
    pareja1: String,
    pareja2: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("casados", casados)
```

my code in the marry command is

look for the model

```
let modelo = await casados.findOne({ $or: [{pareja1: interaction.user.id}, {pareja2: interaction.user.id}]})
```

If it doesn't find it, create a new one.

```
if(!modelo) modelo = new casados({
         pareja1: interaction.user.id,
         pareja2: pareja.id
       })
       await modelo.save()
```

then on my command divorce

look for the model again

```
let modelo = await casados.findOne({ $or: [{pareja1: interaction.user.id}, {pareja2: interaction.user.id}]})
```

and delete it

```
await casados.findOneAndDelete({
        $or: [
            {pareja1: interaction.user.id},
            {pareja2: interaction.user.id}
        ]}).catch(e=> { console.log(e)})
```